# Android dep: How to calculate the frequency of an audio pitch

Tags: android, fft, frequency, visualizer

How to calculate the frequency of an audio pitch,such as International standard `pitch = 440Hz` . I try to use Visualizer to get the frequency , but I don't understand the means of the method `getFft()`; it got the `byte[]` data,and I don't know what means of the data is. How can I use `getFft()` to calculate the frequency.
I mean, I play a media(eg.`International standard pitch = 440Hz`),and I want to the calculate  frequency by Visualizer (440Hz), how should I do?
please help me!

Comment: What have you done so far?  With what step do you need help?

Comment: thx for your comment,here is china,maybe you'r sleeping right now, I show you my code , i'm looking forward to your reply

Comment: why I cant post my code ...

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.